# how to create migration script with foreign key

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to create tables with foreign key through my migration script.

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string :title
end

create_table :comments do |t|
  t.references :post
end
```

after `rake db:migrate`, comments was not referred by post through id.

How to create this in rails-2.2.3?

Answer (score 0):

You can create migration as normal table schema and use :primary_key option for belongs_to for broader support of legacy schemas and those using a separate foreign key:

`belongs_to :posts, :foreign_key => 'post_id'`

Comment: I want to do this in database level.